# ERROR in sql: sql command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle

when I execute this query from the visual studio I get the ERROR "sql command not properly ended" but when I execute it from the plsql it is work without errors.
The query is:

```
select animal_type_id, animal_type_name, animal_name
from animal natural join animal_type
where animal_type_id not in (select animal_type_id from animal
   where animal.recieving_date>(sysdate-365))
```

what can I do?
thanks

Comment: Which DBMS Do you use?

Comment: Visual Studio is not a database server. Which database are you trying to use? NATURAL JOIN is not supported in SQL Server.

Comment: This is the Oracle documentation of this error: [ORA-00933](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00933.php)

Comment: Try the SQL without the `natural` in the join within Visual Studio.

Comment: When you say *Visual Studio*, what do you mean?  Are you executing some SQL from some C# code perhaps? Are you using ODP.NET? If so, please post the relevant code.

Comment: @sstan: He could be using [ODT](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index-097110.html) for Visual Studio.

Comment: I am executeing some sql from c# code in WPF project

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if Visual Studio messes up your SQL, this is not an ORACLE-related question.

Try to run the statement `select animal_type_id from animal where animal.recieving_date>(sysdate-365)` and see if that works properly. Then run the `select animal_type_id, animal_type_name, animal_name from animal natural join animal_type where animal_type_id not in` - statement alone, with a fixed number of animal_type_id.

Just to make sure: You did end that SQL-Statement with `;`? No idea if Visual Studio needs it, better check!